# redirecting users to another page

Tags: php, html

I am wondering if it's possible to redirect a user to another page from a php file after a delay of some kind.

I.E user will click send this will then show them what has been sent and then re-direct them back to the home page.

Comment: Javascript redirect called via setTimeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the body sent (showing the "Message sent" thing), using `header("Location:...");` is out of the question.

Just do it in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {location.href="...";},2000); // 2000 ms = 2 seconds
</script>
```

Comment: can i use javascript within PHP?

Comment: Sure. Just use `echo` to output it.

Comment: @mitchnufc, Just to clarify, Kolink and I are not in disagreement here.  You cannot use JavaScript within PHP.  However, you can use PHP to output JavaScript, and that JavaScript is then ran client-side.

Comment: Well put, Brad. I was just thinking how can I clarify this, but you sniped me again :p

Comment: so would i just echo the whole script?

Comment: <?php <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {location.href="...";},2000); // 2000 ms = 2 seconds
</script> ?>

Comment: Erm... where's the `echo`? Forget that, just remove the `<?php..?>` tags and you're good to go.

Comment: so just like above no need to echo?

Comment: Just... put exactly what I typed somewhere in your code, NOT in `<?php` tags.

Comment: It's not difficult... It really isn't. I'm sorry, but in the interests of my own sanity I'm going to have to stop helping you here... I told you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I wanted to use it in a if statment within php if (true) this page, else this page

Comment: And what, exactly, did you try?

Comment: If i put the script within brackets it won't run, outside it does run but that happens once the if statement is run either way

Comment: Well, you could have the `if` statement set a variable `$redirect_to_url`, then have the script contain `location.href='<?php echo $redirect_to_url; ?>';`.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use:

```
header('Refresh: 10; url=http://www.example.com');
```

This will redirect after 10 seconds. Although it's not the best way to do it. As stated below, don't break the back button...

Comment: "This method is considered by the W3C to be a poor method of redirection, since it does not communicate any information about either the original or new resource, to the browser. The W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (7.4) discourage the creation of auto-refreshing pages[...]. Some articles that they have written on the issue include W3C Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (1.0): Ensure user control of time-sensitive content changes and Use standard redirects: don't break the back button!" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header)